# Does this bounty case look kind of fishy?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, accepted-answer

[How to display an activity indicator with text on iOS 8 with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785715/how-to-display-an-activity-indicator-with-text-on-ios-8-with-swift)

In this question, I wrote a really simple and good answer and got (+6, -3). (The minuses are probably from the other guys posting an answer)

The guy told me he would award me a bounty:

> haha, I ended up finding the code before I read your update. Okay, great, have the bounty - p.s: SO wants me to wait 23 hours

Then another guy https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leonardo-savio-dabus comes along and answers the question with (+1, -2). I think his answer has bonus features with disabling buttons, but that was not asked for in a question. Also more than 50% of his code doesn't have anything to do with the ops question. Like applying filters and buttons. And there literally is no explanation, no comments just dumb code.

The votes I got indicate that my answer is better. Plus I think that the op is a newbie swift programmer and therefore could not make sense of Leonardo's answer. How do I know?

> @Esq where in the code are you setting the background of the main view to black? I don't want that :p

Well its like the third line in my code and its so obvious, even a non programmer could find where I was setting the background of the main view black.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

So anyways, I thought there was something fishy and knew Rodrigo could not make sense and use Leonardo's code. I went and searched Rodrigo's Swift questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:413570+[swift] and I found out that

Out of all Rodrigo's 5 swift questions:

- 1 question edited by Leonardo
- 1 question got rewarded bounty by Leonardo
- 1 question edited and answered by Leonardo
- 1 question got commented by Leonardo
- 1 question answered by Leonardo

Oh and plus these guys are both from Brazil. I have no doubt that Leonardo is a good swift programmer. But I post simple swift questions a lot and never saw Leonardo until this incident.

Do you guys think there is something fishy here? Are these guys in contact and swapping votes? Can the moderators check this case out?

Answer (score 20):

Flag one of the posts involved and explain in the *Other* flag dialog your suspicions. A moderator will then investigate.

There is no point in posting this on Meta though. We cannot see what moderators can see. You certainly found something a little suspicious but you need to see what other correlations there are in information not made public.

However, if there turns out to be a perfectly innocent reason for the connections between the two accounts, you just paraded two established users in front of the Meta crowd, some of whom carry rotten tomatoes (down votes) they'll happily throw at anything suspicious, without evidence.